# How to include Javascript scripts inside Javascript on the client side?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am making an HTML5 game engine. There is only one file that is supposed to be included in the HTML file, which is engine.js. That script is supposed to create a global Engine object that can be used in other scripts by the user. The Engine object is a wrapper for all classes and functions in the engine, but, I would like to separate the engine into different files. I think that it would be a bit sloppy if the were all supposed to be included by the user, so how can I have the engine.js include the automatically?

(Something like require() in Node.js.)

Comment: You're about to get a ton of answers....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at  [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It is a library which fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to use a javascript to javascript compiler like [Closure Tools](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). Using RequireJs your client will still be making multiple http GETs to fetch each file (IIRC), 
using the closure tools your seperate javascript files will be combined into one (also minified and stripped of deadcode.)

This comes with pros and cons, some of the cons include,

- Less reuse of users cache
- full reload if you change any one file

Answer (score 1):

A pure JavaScript approach isn't as straightforward as you might expect, since JS can only work its magic when the pre-flight checks have been finished. Including scripts with JavaScript is possible; however, using the "global scope" is even more off-limits than it otherwise would be.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = 'scripts/yourScript.js';
    newScript.onload = yourNormalOnload;
    // or newScript.onreadystatechange = yourNormalOnload;
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
}

function yourNormalOnload()
{
    //use whatever functions declared in yourScript.js here
}
```

In this example, `yourNormalOnload` function would be your script, but in order to have access to the script you get on the fly, you have to wrap it all up in a callback function, that is called once the included script has been loaded. Thankfully, appending a script fires an `onload` or `onreadystatechange` event, so you can listen for that.

---

You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) response, the code is pretty much the same, but offers a lot more of explanation than I did.